# Which sentence among the four makes sense?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

73) Choose the only alternative that is correct:

> a) Janet pretends to be a famous actress when she grows up.
>
> b) One of the things I like about my boss is that she is very comprehensive. She really understands us - especially when we have problems.
>
> c) I am sorry, but it will not be possible to anticipate your appointment. I already have another compromise before yours.
>
> d) John is fortunate to have such an understanding boss.

Sentence a) seems to be wrong. ' Janet intends to be...' should be a better option. - Sentence d) seems a bit awkward ' understanding boss'. I had never heard that before. - I don't know what is wrong with sentences b) and c). I think that either b) or c) should be the right choice.

Comment: What are the alternatives???

Comment: There are four alternatives: a) b) c) and d). Only one of them is correct.

Comment: Which ones do you think could be the correct answer?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the sentences?

Comment: - Sentence a) seems to be wrong. ' Janet intends to be...' should be a better option. - Sentence d) seems a bit awkward ' understanding boss'. I had never heard that before. - I don't know what is wrong with sentences b) and c). I think that either b) or c) should be the right choice.

Comment: d is correct. "understanding boss" is common. You're right on a, but there's actually an older definition of pretend "to claim to be" that works. "When she grows up, Janet claims to be a famous actress." The tense is that used for things you're sure of happening in the future. b uses "comprehensive" in an older way, modernly it means "leaving nothing out" not "understanding." c has anticipate and compromise as very, very odd usages that don't have any meaning I'm aware of. It sounds like nonsense.

Comment: @modulusshift That's an answer!

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker I can tell you d) is the only answer that makes sense on a first read. The other three sentences are valid English but don't really make sense, they have at least one word that should be replaced with another for them to make sense.

A) pretends - intends
B) comprehensive - empathatic
C) anticipate - consider, compromise - engagement

Comment: While you aren't wrong, explaining why the word choices are wrong or right would be more helpful than simply providing the right answer. I am not the source of the down vote btw. The comment by modulusshift is an example of what I mean.

Comment: Well I have explained what the wrong words are for the other sentences and what they could be replaced with to make meaningful sentence

Comment: Which I why I didn't DV, but I think the answer would be improved with some elaboration so that it could be applied to other sentences and situations. There are other words than "empathetic" that might be used in B for example - why choose that particular one? Why not understanding or perceptive?

Comment: Well yes, but I was just trying to be helpful. Surely downvotes are for wrong answers anyway rather than correct answers but answers that dont contain as much information as you would like.